# How to overcome Google penalties for blogger

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, blogger

Suddenly my blog stop appearing in Google search & there is a huge dip in traffic, i went to webmaster tool & applied for re consideration.
i don't no the exact reason why it happened like that, i forgot to add Disclaimer would it cause problem?
How to identify what makes google to remove my blog from search index?
Does google reconsider my blog? are there any alternatives for it?

Comment: When did this happen?

Comment: on 2nd of Aug, i dont no what mistake i have done.. can u please help me

Comment: A new update went out 22 July, which is why I asked about the date. http://www.seroundtable.com/panda-23-13766.html So that doesn't explain it.

Comment: Now what is the solution.. i submitted for reconsideration on the same day, still no response yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Before submitting for reconsideration, ensure that your site meets Google's guidelines : http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769

Check as well that your robots.txt isn't blocking Google from properly crawling (and thus indexing) your site.